# FULL JOIN in MySQL connectiong 6 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about FULL JOIN at MySql. I know that alternative is UNION but I have dificulties to combine them all.

I guess it would be already enough to get answer on 4 tables as 5th and 6th are same as in first 4.

**Tables: Bill, Service, BS, Item, BI, Buyer**

*BS* connect more *Services* to *Bill* and *BI* connect more *Items* to *Bill*. *Buyer* is 1:1 relation with *Bill*.

## Tables example:

```
Bill:
----------------------
id | number | Buyer_id
1  | 12014  |    3
2  | 22014  |    2
3  | 32014  |    5

Services:
----------------------
id | cost
1  |   2
2  |   7
3  |   1
4  |  12

BS:
----------------------
id | Bill_id | Services_id
1  |    1    |     3
2  |    1    |     4
3  |    2    |     2
4  |    3    |     1
5  |    3    |     2
6  |    3    |     3
7  |    3    |     4

Item:
----------------------
id | cost
1  |  34
2  |  77
3  |   2
4  |  15
5  |  13

BI:
----------------------
id | Bill_id | Items_id
1  |    1    |    5
2  |    2    |    3
3  |    3    |    2

Buyer:
----------------------
id | name
1  | John
2  | Mary
3  | Dave
4  | Carl
5  | Jack
```

So far the closest I got to was that I used following SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM Bill b
LEFT JOIN BI ON BI.Bill_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN BS ON BS.Bill_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN Item i ON i.id = BI.Item_id
LEFT JOIN Services s ON s.id = BS.Services_id
LEFT JOIN Buyer ON Buyer.id = b.Buyer_id
WHERE b.number = '12014'
```

Result gives me 2 Services and 1 duplicated Item but I want one Item and one NULL item (as only one item is attached to that bill.

Result that I get (just ids as it's shorter):

```
b.id | s.id | BS.id | i.id | BI.id | Buyer.id
  1  |   3  |   1   |  1   |   5   |   3
  1  |   4  |   2   |  1   |   5   |   3
```

And desired result in table:

```
b.id | s.id | BS.id | i.id | BI.id | Buyer.id
  1  |   3  |   1   |  1   |   5   |   3
  1  |   4  |   2   | NULL | NULL  |   3 (or NULL, doesn't really matter)
```

I tried with others as well but I got even more rows than 2 (note that two are expected or if Bill.number=32014 then 4 rows).

Thank you!

Comment: Since you don't have any join clauses between `BI` and `BS`, you get a cross-product of them.

Comment: @Barmar . . . A join condition would be redundant.  Both are joined to the same value, `b.id`.

Comment: You're not really storing currency symbols are you?

Comment: No symbols, I adjusted that example for easier overview ;)

Comment: How is this related to `FULL JOIN`?  The results you are getting make sense, how would you choose which item_ID and BI_ID are `NULL` despite joining?

Comment: Why this result is getting sense? If I read that in my application it tells me that on that bill there are two items but I have only one relation to one item. I've put full join because I wanted solutions with null result not with duplicated inserts like in this example: [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-full-joins.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking the wrong approach.

The result of a query to a relational database is a relation - you may treat it as a rectangular matrix with rows and columns. Every row represents *something* (at least it should), every column represents an *attribute* and every cell represents the thing's attribute's value.

```
          |  [attr 1]   |  [attr 2]
-----------+---------------+-------------------------
[thing 1] |   value     |   some value
[thing 2] |   value     |   other value
[thing 3] |   a value   |   yeah, a value
```

Now here is what you are trying to produce:

```
          |  [attr 1]   |  [attr 2]      |                   |  [other attr 3]
-----------+---------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------
[thing 1] |   value     |   some value   |  [other thing 1]  |   a value
[thing 2] |   value     |   other value  |
```

See? Attempting to return two relations with a single query. Not rectangular anymore, huh? Items and services are independent here, but you are trying to put them into a single row. Don't go this way, here are three queries for you:

```
-- Get bill/buyer details (1 row)
SELECT b.id, Buyer.id
FROM Bill b
LEFT JOIN Buyer ON Buyer.id = b.Buyer_id
WHERE b.number = '12014';

-- Get billed items (1 row per item)
SELECT BI.id, i.id
FROM Bill b
JOIN BI ON BI.Bill_id = b.id
JOIN Item i ON i.id = BI.Item_id
WHERE b.number = '12014';

-- Get billed services (1 row per service)
SELECT BS.id, s.id
FROM Bill b
JOIN BS ON BS.Bill_id = b.id
JOIN Services s ON s.id = BS.Services_id
WHERE b.number = '12014';
```

Note that item and services queries don't use left joins. You would like to return 0 rows if there are no items/services on the bill.

Then handle the results of them one by one in your application.

***Edit:***

Sometimes two (or more) entities share some common characteristics, for example in your application you could treat services and items as bill lines. In this case, this could be valid to retrieve all of them in a single query, but only this way using union:

```
-- Get bill lines (items and services)
SELECT BI.id AS bill_item_id, i.id AS item_id, NULL as bill_service_id, NULL as service_id
FROM Bill b
JOIN BI ON BI.Bill_id = b.id
JOIN Item i ON i.id = BI.Item_id
WHERE b.number = '12014';
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS bill_item_id, NULL AS item_id, BS.id as bill_service_id, s.id as service_id
FROM Bill b
JOIN BS ON BS.Bill_id = b.id
JOIN Services s ON s.id = BS.Services_id
WHERE b.number = '12014';
```

Which will return a result similar to what you originally expected:

```
BI.id |  i.id | BS.id | s.id
  5   |   1   | NULL | NULL
NULL  | NULL  |  1   |  3
NULL  | NULL  |  2   |  4
```

Note that:

- each item and service is an individual bill line represented by a record. Don't try to artificially "compress" data across rows or columns
- it's not the case in your schema, but most often there are also some shared attributes, like line id, quantity ordered or amount paid.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, I was affraid that I will not be able to do that in one sql query an you told me exactly that. I guess I'll have to adjust my application after all. Btw, I knew about this solution but I wanted database to hande this as then it is only one query instead of 3 to execute. This can save time in aplications or on slow internet connections. I will not accept that answer yet as I want to give others chance to answer as well but if nothing comes up... Thank you for that answer!

Comment: You usually have database on the same server or local network at least. Anyway, see my update.

Comment: Maybe in some cases you have and in some you don't. In my case I don't have as multiple applications are using it (android, servers and desktop applications) and phones are quicker with one query instead of 3. This sollution is a lot better now, thank you!